# Elements not showing in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am using GridBagLayout as JFrame layout. My elements are not showing no matter what i write. Please don't give answers which use anything but GridBagLayout(sorry if it sound rude)

[image]

```
JPanel Panel;
    JButton insertButton = new JButton("Insert");
    GridBagConstraints gbc;

    public MainFrame() {

        this.setTitle("JAVA & MySQL");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(500, 100, 600, 600);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        Panel.setOpaque(true);
        Panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        Panel.add(insertButton, gbc);




    }
```

Comment: Move setVisible to the end of the method or call revalidate and repaint at the end of the method

Comment: No matter where it is, it's the same

Comment: Did you actually add Panel to anything?

Comment: The code looks incomplete omho. It might be that you are not adding your panel to your top-level container so you basically create it but the content is not added and thus not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you didn't add the panel to the top-level container's content pane. Call `this.add(panel)` to make it happen.

Besides, as @MaddProgrammer said in his comment, you should call `pack()` and `setVisible()` methods after adding all the components, otherwise you have to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` in order to validate the components hierarchy.

As per [Container#add(Component comp)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-) documentation:

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore,
>   invalidates the component hierarchy. **If the container has already been
>   displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to
>   display the added component.**

In addition you shouldn't mix absolute layout calls such as `setBounds()`, `setLocation()` or `setSize()` (just avoid them) and layout managers (these ones are highly recommended)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not clear whats where (is this code inside your frame class) and you have chosen names poorly. By convention field names should start witha lower case letter (to distinguish them from class names).

It appears you never add your panel to the frame, and also you never pack() the frame.

Alter the code like this:

```
public MainFrame() {
    this.setTitle("JAVA & MySQL");
    // setting visible should come last!
    //this.setVisible(true);
    this.setBounds(500, 100, 600, 600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    Panel.setOpaque(true);
    Panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.weightx = 1;
    gbc.weighty = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    Panel.add(insertButton, gbc);

    // put the panel into the frame!
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(Panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```